# Make C# source run as a script?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting

I am doing a little scripting and i find sometime more power would be nice. Like the ability to keep trying to delete a file with a 1sec delay AND have it portable. I spent some time today translating a bat script to bash. I know i can use php or python but i VERY MUCH PREFER static/compile time checking.

Is there a way to run C# code as a script? As long as i can edit the source quickly (like in a notepad) and run it simply then i'll be happy.

I am hoping i dont have to create a custom ext and write a app to dynamically compile and execute the script (i know have source to compile .js somewhere...). Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: There's PowerShell if you want access to the .NET library (as well as a bunch of commandlets).  F# also has an interactive mode which will give you access to .NET libraries from a console.  Either of those seems like a more straight forward solution than compiling C# on the fly.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. You want to be able to "edit the source quickly and run it", but you "prefer static/compile time checking". Do you want a language that is *interpreted* or one that is *compiled*?

Comment: you could use either csscript or linqpad as answered. I use csscript for every complex batch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there's CS-Script.
http://csscript.net/

Haven't used it much myself though.

Answer (score 6):

```
> copy con cs.bat
csc -o OUTPUT.exe %1
OUTPUT.exe
del OUTPUT.exe
^Z
> cs somefile.cs
```

Here is a better version of a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo using System; class P { static void Main() { > foo.cs
type %1 >> foo.cs
echo }} >> foo.cs
csc /nologo /out:foo.exe foo.cs
del foo.cs
foo.exe
del foo.exe
```

So you have some file called foo.txt:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

Invoke it like:

```
cs.bat foo.txt
```

Comment: I might very well do this if i get sick of writing namespaces or if i feel like having built in functions.

Comment: @leppie thanks for this, I've used your code as a base for a handy batch file of my own: https://gist.github.com/3018417

Answer (score 3):

Mono has [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) which is an interactive shell for C#

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to execute a small snippet to perform something in C# I just fire up [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Perhaps it includes a bit to much for simply small scripts but it beats making a new console project every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shell developed by mono project developers name  [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl). I have never tried, but it seems very interesting.